# multiple instances of a JNI wrapper

Tags: java, java-native-interface, instance

I have a class Modbus

```
public class Modbus {
  // init TCP
  public native void init(String ip, int port, int id);
  public native short[] read_registers(int slaveid, int addr, int len);
```

the `id` in the init method, will be printed to the stdout if I execute `read_registers`

if I do

```
Modbus mb1 = new Modbus("192.168.0.250", 502, 1);
Modbus mb2 = new Modbus("192.168.0.250", 502, 2);
```

and then

```
mb1.read_registers(....);
mb2.read_registers(....);
```

in both cases it prints `2` to the stdout. So it seems the second instance overwrites the first. How can I use multiple instances of the jni-wrapper?

EDIT:

Here the C code I'm using, my goal is to use multiple connections to the samre or different modbus devices

```
#include "eu_company_lib_comm_modbus_Modbus.h"
#include <modbus/modbus-rtu.h>
#include <modbus/modbus.h>
#include <errno.h>
modbus_t *mb;
int readError;
int writeError;
int errnr;
const char* errStr;
int c_id;
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL 
Java_eu_company_lib_comm_modbus_Modbus_init__Ljava_lang_String_2I(
    JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jstring ip, jint port, jint id) {

const char* c_ip = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, ip, 0);
mb = modbus_new_tcp(c_ip, port);
c_id=id;
if (mb == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate libmodbus context\n");
    fflush(stderr);
    return;
}
modbus_set_debug(mb, 1);

if (modbus_connect(mb) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Connection failed: %s\n",     modbus_strerror(errno));
    fflush(stderr);
    modbus_free(mb);
    return;
}

(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, ip, c_ip);
}
JNIEXPORT jshortArray JNICALL Java_eu_company_lib_comm_modbus_Modbus_read_1registers(
    JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint slave_id, jint address, jint len) {

jshortArray result = (*env)->NewShortArray(env, len);
uint16_t tab_reg[len];
printf("%d\n",c_id);
fflush(stdout);
readError = modbus_read_registers(mb, address, len, tab_reg);

errnr = errno;
errStr = modbus_strerror(errno);

(*env)->SetShortArrayRegion(env, result, 0, len, tab_reg);

return result;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the Stackoverflow crystal ball for reading your mind is defect today - you really have to edit your question and add more details (e.g more code) about the Modbus class and about the native implementation you use.

Comment: Well the answer is simple in the JNI part you are using global variables like `int c_id;` - if you do so you can not expect that it works with multiple instances.

Comment: ok, I thought I could use the jni part multiple times. So I would have to extend the jni part, to be able to handle multiple connections...? or I could return the modbus_t object to java, and pass this to every read/write method

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to let Java do the job. Remove all the global variables in the JNI part. Create instance fields in the Java ModBus class and access them on the JNI level.

Comment: for this I would have to switch to c++? I just returned the pointer address of the modbus_t variable to java, and passed them to any methods where I need it

Comment: A simple answer: no

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that in the JNI part you are using global variables. Global variables. Therefore those variables are not related in any way to an `Modbus` instance.

From my point of view you should move as much code from JNI into the Java implementation of `ModBus` and use local fields for storing all the persistent values you need on Java an JNI level:

public class Modbus {

```
private final String ip;
private final int port;
private final int id;

public ModBus(String ip, int port, ind id) {
     this.ip = ip;
     this.port = port;
     this.id = id;
}    

// init TCP
public native void init(String ip, int port, int id);
public native short[] read_registers(int slaveid, int addr, int len);
```

}

On JNI side you can access al the Java fields for retrieving the values using the JNI methods `GetObjectClass(..)`, `GetFieldID(..)` and `GetObjectField(..)`.

Search SO for examples you will find a lot of them for C and C++.

Alternatively you can make the native methods private and add a wrapper method that on every calls delivers the needed values to the JNI part:

```
public void init() {
    init(ip, port, id);
}

private native void init(String ip, int port, int id);
```